# One Time Password with GAM

Tags: genexus, genexus-gam

I'm trying to set in my Genexus project a "one time password" using the GAM and I'm following [this](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?48254,GAM%20-%20Two%20Factor%20Authentication%20https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?48197,GAM%20-%20One%20Time%20Password%20%28OTP%29) [and this](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?48197,GAM%20-%20One%20Time%20Password%20%28OTP%29) pages on the wiki

I created the new authentication type

[image]

Set it as OTP for the local authentication type

[image]

Added the data for sending the mail (the same mail address is in all the three censored fields, an outlook mail)

[image]

And then I tell the user to use the 2FA, but I get this error (translated from italian, it could be slightly different)

> "Failed to validate user in OTP custom event (GAM431)"

I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Am I missing a step? The user has a valid email address and the sending email address has the correct settings. What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your OTP authentication type you need to uncheck the property "Utilizzare per l'autenticazione del primo fattore" to use it as second factor.

Please let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: It's not working, same error. But actually it was wrong that it was checked